# Redirecting to a new page after successful login

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I'm sure this question has been asked before but I have searched thoroughly for an answer but to no avail. (The only answers I've seen involve ajax) But I'm using just javascript, PHP and HTML.

I have a login.php page and I have already created a  HTML page which is to be the landing page right after a user is successfully logged in. How do I go about this?

The following is my code for the login page and the landing page after the login is called transfer.html:

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
  <div id="content">
     <h3>Login to Internet Banking</h3>
     <form id="login" action="" method="post">
        <p>
          <label for="userid">UserID:</label>
          <input type="text" name="UserID" id="UserID"/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="PIN">PIN:</label>
          <input type="password" name="PIN" id="PIN" />
        </p>

        <p>
          <input type="submit" name="btnSend" value="Login" class="submit_button" />

        </p>
      </form>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <p>
        Not yet registered?
 <a href="registration.php">Click here to register</a>
 </p>

  <div id="wrap">
        <!-- start PHP code -->
        <?php

            mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to database server(localhost) with UserID and PIN.
            mysql_select_db("registrations") or die(mysql_error()); // Select registration database.

            if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['PIN']) && !empty($_POST['PIN'])){
                $UserID = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
                $PIN = mysql_escape_string(md5($_POST['PIN']));

                $search = mysql_query("SELECT UserID, PIN, active FROM users WHERE UserID='".$UserID."' AND PIN='".$PIN."' AND active='1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
                $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

                if($match > 0){
                    $msg = 'Login Complete! Thanks';
                }else{
                    $msg = 'Login Failed!<br /> Please make sure that you enter the correct details and that you have activated your account.';
                }
            }


        ?>
        <!-- stop PHP Code -->
        <?php 
            if(isset($msg)){ // Check if $msg is not empty
                echo '<div class="statusmsg">'.$msg.'</div>'; // Display our message and add a div around it with the class statusmsg
            } ?>

    </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: what do you really want?

Comment: Take a look at [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: First of all, you should specify in <FORM> tag ACTION value that is the page which will log you in. The other thing is that if you have your .html file one surely can bypass your login.php and open .html page directly. Third thing is I don't know what your PHP code is going to do, probably you should take your HTML part to first site and this PHP code to other php page that makes logging.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, move all your PHP code to the top. Without it, my code below wont work.

To do the redirect, use:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Also, please consider my advice. Since it's not the first question today and all your questions are related to basics, you should consider reading some good PHP book to understand how things work.

Here you can find useful links to free books:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Answer (score 11):

> **Javascript redirection generated with php code:**

```
 if($match > 0){
     $msg = 'Login Complete! Thanks';
     echo "<script> window.location.assign('index.php'); </script>";
 }
 else{
     $msg = 'Login Failed!<br /> Please make sure that you enter the correct  details and that you have activated your account.';
 }
```

> **Php redirection only:**

```
<?php
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: your answer was a divine gift for my project. Thank you good sir!

Comment: This answer worked. Is there any security issues for using this method?

Answer (score 0):

Try header("Location:home.php"); instead of showing $msg = 'Login Complete! Thanks';
Hope it'll help you.

Comment: It won't work, since headers can't be set before any output from php script.

Comment: Put your php script under if(isset($_POST['btnSend']) && $_POST['btnSend']=='Login') this codition.

Comment: Once again, there should be no output. The first line of the file, "<div id="content">" is an output already, so all headers should be set  before that line.

Comment: then use your full site url like header("Location:http://www.website.com/home.php"); Hope it'll be work.

Comment: Thanks guys, all your answers were very helpful. And I'll be taking all the advice.

Comment: Please read http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php to understand what is headers and how to use them. It doesn't matter what link you put inside, the issue is that you can't set any headers if you have even single character of output before.

This won't work:

"test<?php header(...); ?> "

;while this will:

"<?php header(...); ?>test"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `location` header as follows:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Replacing `http://www.example.com` of course with the url of your landing page.

Add this where you have finished logging the user in.

**Note**: When redirecting the user will be immediately redirected so you're message probably won't display.

Additionally, you need to move your PHP code to the top of the file for this solution to work.

On another side note, please see my comment above regarding the use of the deprecated `mysql` statements and consider using the newer, safer and improved `mysqli` or `PDO` statements.

Answer (score 0):

May be use like this

```
if($match > 0){
 $msg = 'Login Complete! Thanks';
 echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>link</a>";
 }
else{
 $msg = 'Login Failed!<br /> Please make sure that you enter the correct  details and that you have activated your account.';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also provide a link to the page after login and have it auto redirect using javascript after 10 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Just add the following code after the final message you give using PHP code

Print'window.location.assign("index.php")

Comment: Is this php or javascript ? could you check the syntax please ?

Comment: This question was answered - and accepted - three years ago.  What value does your new answer bring? Additionally, the formatting is incorrect, and your code is not valid PHP.